# ROS cannot communicate over network under Natty

Tags: ros, communication, ubuntu-natty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After updating to Natty, ROS can't communicate locally via network ports no more.

```
Unable to contact my own server at [http://hostname:48064/].
```

Changing/setting the variables `ROS_MASTER_URI`, `ROS_HOSTNAME` and `ROS_IP` according to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/1204/unable-to-contact-my-own-server) didn't help. The tests according to the [ROS network troubleshooting guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) were partially successful.

1. `ping` works for `127.0.0.1`, for `localhost` and for the hostname.
2. `netcat` works for `127.0.0.1` and for `localhost`, but not for the hostname.

Sorry, in case this is a rather pathetic network problem. Maybe it's something specific to Natty?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10375/ros-cannot-communicate-over-network-under-natty/) by [Mark](https://answers.ros.org/users/742/mark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mark](https://answers.ros.org/users/742/mark/) on 2011-06-23**:
No, I substituted my actual hostname with `hostname`

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-23**:
Does the error message literally show 'http://hostname:48064/' or your hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright... it *was* a rather pathetic network problem. Actually I don't know why, but after the update to Natty, my `/etc/hosts` file didn't contain the IP adress from my local network anymore. The following entry fixed this.

```
192.168.1.XXX    hostname
```

---

Originally posted by [Mark](https://answers.ros.org/users/742/mark/) with karma: 16 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0